# Common mistakes when importing timeseries-timestamps (from csv.data) into R, which are labeled as characters, but need to be DateTime

Tags: r, csv, datetime, import, character

I want to Import a timeseries (from .csv) into R, but the timestamps are Always characters and not DateTimes so I want to convert them. Despite of telling R the "Right Version" of %m/%d/%Y, R is Always producing NAs.
Are there common mistakes I could make

%d.%m.%Y %H:%M

Comment: It would be helpful to share in your question some lines of the CSV so we can see what you're starting from, and to share also what code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

use the `tidyverse` library

Try using `read_csv`

use `lubridate` library for date handling, the syntax is pretty simple, `dmy`, `ymd`, etc

Give it a go